What is $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I^{n}$, is topology is Tychonoff subspace topology?
I want to know what is  $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I^{n}$ with $I=[0,1]$.
Im not sure if is just:
$$\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I^{n}=\{(x_{n})\in \prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}}I^{n}\mid \exists ~M\subseteq \mathbb{N}:|M|\leq \omega~\wedge~ \forall~n\in \mathbb{N}\setminus M,~x_{n}=0\}$$
This strange set depend of $M$? And then, for example $x_{2}\in I^{2}$ and so $x_{3}\in I^{3}$ ? Where do we study that kind of stuffs? I find this set studying some notions of infinte dimensions of topological spaces.
Thanks for the help.

This symbol typically denotes the (infinite) direct sum, i.e. the set of all sequences $(x_n)$ such that $x_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. It is strange however to use it with $[0,1]^n$, it typically arises in the context of groups/modules. Where did you see that?

In Sakai, Geometric Aspects of General Topology. But I dosen't explain what is...

I would guess that this means the disjoint union. At a skim, here Sakai uses the symbol $\bigoplus$ a few times while referring to it as the "topological sum", which refers to this notion. This makes some sense as it's the coproduct in Top. (Also, in your definition, I guess you mean $|M| < \omega$)

So then? $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}I^{n}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}{(x,n)\mid x\in I^{n} }$
